# browserstack configuration Task Invalid URI in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, automated-tests, browserstack

I am using azure Devops and I am integrating browserstack in my azure pipeline and when I Run the pipeline ut fail in `BrowserStack configuration setup` and it showed me this error

```
Error: Invalid URI "https:///#$@api.browserstack.com/automate/plan.json"
```

my YAML is

```
steps:
- task: browserstackcom.browserstack-vsts-extension.browserstack-config-task.BrowserStackConfig@0
  displayName: 'BrowserStack configuration setup'
  inputs:
    BrowserStackServiceEndPoint: BrowserStack
    browserstackLocal: true
    bsLocalOptions: ' {"verbose": true, "forceLocal": true} '
```

and I have already test the connection

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Medhat,
According to the screenshot, I have tested it and it works, could you create a new service connection and try it again? If the issue still occurs, please set the variable system.debug to true and then share the full log screenshot in the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you are using an incorrect Hub URL for your configuration. Could you try using the below format of the URL?

```
https://USERNAME:AUTOMATE_KEY@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub
```

Comment: Thank you It was AUTOMATE_KEY instead of my password